# Fedora 38 KDE Updates - Discover doesn't trigger reboot over remote (xrdp) session

Tags: fedora, kde, xrdp

I have a Fedora VM installed in Hyper-V and have connected to it via RDP (xrdp). I am able to access the Updates - Discover screen and click "Update All", however, I am not prompted afterwards to reboot the system.

I assume there is some polkit rule that is explicitly preventing this? (I tried to find the rule but they all appear to be defaulted to AUTH_ADMIN however, I am not receiving the authentication prompt as it did when I clicked "Refresh")